# Java mouseDown Event object

Tags: java, graphics, event-handling

When you use the method

```
public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y)
```

in Java, what does the Event object do or what is it used for? I am trying to write a program that involves someone clicking on a rectangle created by

```
g.fillRect(horizontal position,vertical position,height,width);
```

I presume you use event handling to pick up the click on the rectangle with the mousedown method, but how can u do this? Please provide examples in your answers. I did my research on Google, and found nothing, even with really specific searches. Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mouseDown is a mouse event. What you need to do is add an event listener to your program, so when the mouse is clicked an event handler calls a method. In this method you want to see if the x,y position of the mouse is within the rectangle.

You will need to implement MouseListener    "implements MouseListener"

```
// import an extra class for the MouseListener 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class YourClassName extends Applet implements MouseListener 
{
     int x = horizontal position;
     int y = vertical position;
     g.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
     addMouseListener(this); 

     // These methods always have to present when you implement MouseListener
     public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent mouseEvent) {} 
     public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent mouseEvent) {} 
     public void mousePressed (MouseEvent mouseEvent) {} 
     public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent mouseEvent) {}  
     public void mouseExited (MouseEvent mouseEvent) {}  

     public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
     mouseX = mouseEvent.getX();
     mouseY = mouseEvent.getY();
     if(mouseX > x && mouseY > y && mouseX < x+width && mouseY < y+height){
         //
         // do whatever 
         //
     }
}
```

for more...
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

Answer (score 2):

The Event object contains information like the

1. **x** and **y** coordinates of the event,
2. The **target** component on which the event happened
3. **when** the even happened

It provides lot of other information as well. 
**Note:** The method is deprecated in favour of processMouseEvent().

Comment: You really should attach a separate [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) rather than override `processMouseEvent`... while `mouseDown` et al. are relics from JDK 1.0.2, directly modifying `processMouseEvent` and friends is a relic from JDK 1.1.

Comment: So how would I know whether the person clicked the rectangle?

Comment: compare the rectangle's coordinates to event.x and event.y

Comment: Given a [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html), you can use any of the overloaded `contains` methods... for example, `rectangle.contains(event.getPoint())` where `event` is a [MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html).

Comment: In the case you don't have a [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html), you can merely do something like...
`Point pt = event.getPoint(); int x = pt.x; int y = pt.y; boolean inside = x >= X1 && x <= X2 && y >= Y1 && y <= Y2;`
... where (X1, Y1), (X2, Y2) are your top-left and bottom-right coordinates of your rectangle, respectively (assuming Java2D screen-space).

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked this

`in Java, what does the Event object do or what is it used for?`

**-** First of all there are `Event Source`, when any **action take place** on the Event Source, an `Event Object` is thrown to the `call back` **method**.

**-** `Call Back` method is the **method inside the** `Listener` (Interface) which is **needed to be implemented** by the `Class` that implements this Listener.

**-** The statements inside this call back method will **dictate whats needed to be done, when the action is done on the Event Source.**

**Eg:**

Assume

```
  Event Source - Button
  When Clicked - Event object is thrown at the call back method
  Call back method - actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) inside ActionListener.
```

**-** In **your example** when the mouse button goes down, the x and y co-ordinate gets noted.
      Then the event object it thrown at its call back method, which needs to be handled by the
      class that implements this Listener.

**-** Its better to use `mousePressed` method of `MouseListener Interface`.

See this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mousePressed%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29